# System.InvalidOperationException: Relational-specific methods can only be used when the context is using a relational database provider

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, xunit, in-memory-database

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>
> Relational-specific methods can only be used when the context is using a relational database provider.

Getting the above mentioned error while using `InMemoryDatabase` for Test Case?

```
var msaContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MSA.DAL.MsaDbContext>()
           .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Get results")
           .ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning))
           .Options;
```

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6080

Comment: InMemory is not intended to be a relational database. In my case i get exactly the same error when unittesting a WCF-service with InMemory. The test that goes wrong asks for the databaseName "dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().Database". I used this test in the past to check if the connection is alive and working, but this cannot be done with InMemory testing.

Comment: If you're using an InMemory database, you'll want to skip running migrations.

Answer (score 37):

Comparing with provider string is brittle - what if Microsoft changes to `Microsoft.EntityFramework` as it moves away from *Core*!

I would recommend to use

```
if (!context.Database.IsInMemory())
{
    context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

or

```
if (context.Database.IsRelational())
{
    context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

we have EF-related code in a separate nuget package that doesn't include `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory`, therefore first option doesn't work for us.

Answer (score 22):

As mentioned by other people I found skipping DBMigration is the best option for now.
I am running Database Migration when Database ProviderName is not InMemory.

```cs
if (context.Database.ProviderName != "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory")
{
    context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the solution of @hemant-sakta didn't work. The cause for the error was that we set the **auto-increment value** in one of our database tables on seeding (we seed during migration).

The solution was to skip setting the auto-increment value when in Isolated Mode:

```
private static void SetAutoIncrementValue(MyContext context)
{
    if (HostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Isolated")) return;
    
    // auto increment code
}
```

Comment: I guess because it has nothing to do with the nature of the database, relational vs non-relational. Your scenario isn't relevant.